# Authenticate data before upload on server in android

Tags: java, android, json, http-headers, http-post

I am developing an android app in which, I am sending some text, files to server. I am using JSON to upload files to server. But I want to provide security to upload data. Data should only get uploaded from android device. In my case if I send data using postman it is get uploaded on server.

php developer told me that, "send data in header". I google it and I found some code.

> Authentication.java

```
public class Authentication  {

    public void AuthenticateData(String url) {

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        httppost.addHeader("userId","someName");
        httppost.addHeader("secretKey","password");

    }
}
```

And I am using it like this way.

```
Authentication authentication
URL = "url_to_upload_data";
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
.
.
authentication.AuthenticateData(URL);
.
List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailid", emailid));
param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_reg", deviceRegNo));
param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",message));"));
JSONObject json_Object = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", param);
```

Is this correct way to do it. Will it be secure?

Comment: Have you tried running the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `AuthentificateData` is not returning anything.

The problem of your approach is that you assume a password can be stored securely on the phone. If you place it in code, even after obfuscation anybody can decompile your sources and read the value.

To provide a secure transfer, you need to use asymmetric cryptography, also refereed as [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) . The public key can be known by anyone and it is safe to store in the phone. You have to protect your server to not leak your private key.

To help in authentication you can also use [digital signatures.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature)

You do not have to implement them from scratch. You have here [simple examples](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/encrypting-with-android-cryptography-api.html) to get started.

Comment: I have done with encryption. since I am new to php. If I visit http header link in browser. will it ask me for credentials

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. You want to have user authentication or not? In any case, using the public key you can encrypt any kind of data securely enough to be passed in plain text http (header or body). You can encode the username and password the same way as text data or binary data. The person who was saying "use headers" refers to the normal process of how authentication and session ids are transferred in http to avoid having to input your password and username everytime you click on a link.